# Generating function of composition with odd part fixed

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, integer-partitions

I have met the following question: consider the set of compositions with any number of parts where each odd part is equal to 1. E.g $(1,2,1,3,1,4,1,\ldots)$. Then I am asked to find the generating function for this set. The hint is that for $k\ge0$, first find the generating function for the set of such compositions of at most $k$ parts.

I think I am pretty confused about generating functions. My understanding is that the generating functions depends on which value we can choose and how many parts of the composition. So for example: choose from $\{1,2\}$ and of part $3$, the GF is simple $(x^1+x^2)^3$...But in case, what is the set of values? Is it $\{1,\ldots,1,2,3,\ldots\}$? So does it mean that the generating function is (assume $k$ is even for now) $$x^{k/2}+\left(\sum_{i=2}^\infty x^i\right)^k?$$

Thanks!!!

Comment: Your example doesn’t match your description: it has odd parts $3$ and $5$, so its odd parts are not all $1$. If you really did mean all compositions whose parts are all either even or $1$, see Theorem $2.4$ of [this PDF](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=B2C71EF57AAA552538702ABBD6F8087E?doi=10.1.1.484.5148&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for pointing this out, I just modified it. Does the Theorem 2.4 still applies?

Comment: I suspect that you are misinterpreting the question. *Odd part* usually means *part whose size is odd*, not *part appearing in an odd-numbered position*. Are you certain that your interpretation is the intended one?

Comment: Hi, the question says the following and I quote : Let $S$  be the set of compositions with any number of parts where each odd part (e.g. first
part, third part, etc.) is equal to $1$.

Comment: Okay; that’s an unusual use of the term, but I agree that it’s unambiguously a reference to position in the composition, not to the parity of the part. In that case the paper to which I linked is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for the paper though, it provides a lot different things that I am not aware of...do you have other hints/suggestions for this question?

Comment: Not until I’ve had a chance to think about it, which may not be until tomorrow; it’s past 02:00 here, and I may call it a day pretty soon.

Comment: thanks! Have a great night!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call compositions of the desired type *good*. Let $a_n$ be the number of good compositions of $n$. Direct calculation shows that $a_1=a_2=1$, $a_3=2$, $a_4=3$, $a_5=5$, and $a_6=8$. These are the Fibonacci numbers and suggest that perhaps $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$ for $n\ge 3$. A bit of thought verifies this. There is an obvious bijection between good compositions of $n$ that end in $1$ and compositions of $n-1$, and there is also a bijection between good compositions of $n$ that end in a number greater than $1$ and compositions of $n-2$: just subtract $2$ from the last part. (It may take a little thought to verify that this really is a bijection.) $0$ has no compositions, so $a_0=0=F_0$, and we already saw that $a_1=1=F_1$, so $a_n=F_n$ for each $n\ge 0$. Thus, the desired generating function is the same as for the Fibonacci numbers and is therefore

$$g(x)=\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}\,.$$

This can of course be found by standard methods from the recurrence and initial conditions if you don’t already know it.

**Added:** The good compositions of $n$ into $2k$ parts are just compositions of $n-k$ into $k$ parts, with a $1$ inserted before each of the $k$ parts, so there are $\binom{n-k-1}{k-1}$ of them. Similarly, the good compositions of $n$ into $2k+1$ parts are just compositions of $n-k-1$ into $k$ parts, so there are $\binom{n-k-2}{k-1}$ of them. Thus, if $g_k$ is the generating function for the number of good compositions into $k$ parts, we have

$$g_{2k}(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n-k-1}{k-1}x^n$$

and

$$g_{2k+1}(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n-k-2}{k-1}x^n\,.$$

From these we can extract the actual functions without too much trouble. For instance,

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n-k-1}{k-1}x^n&=\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n-k-1}{n-2k}x^n\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 2k}\binom{n-k-1}{n-2k}x^n\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n+k-1}nx^{n+2k}\\
&=x^{2k}\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n+k-1}nx^n\\
&=\frac{x^{2k}}{(1-x)^k}\,.
\end{align*}$$

The calculation for $g_{2k+1}(x)$ is very similar.

Comment: Thanks! Although I perhaps need more time to think about the bijection. But it looks very promising!! Just to make sure I understand, the generating series for this set is then $1/(1-g(x))$?

Comment: @CapitalSparrow: No, it’s $g(x)$: $$g(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}F_nx^n=\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nx^n\,.$$

Comment: Thanks! I guess I am being greedy...but is there a way to find  the generating function for the set of such compositions of at most $k$ part? So I might apply String Lemma to it...

Comment: @CapitalSparrow: I don’t know: once I realized what the sequence is, I had an easy way to get $g$ and didn’t bother with the hint that you had. I don’t know the string lemma, at least not by name; what is it?

Comment: M.Scott, the String Lemma says that if we are able to find the GF (say $f_k$) for some subset such that composition is $k$-part, then the GF for the entire set is the sum of all $f_k$ from $k=0$ to $\infty$.

Comment: @CapitalSparrow: Thanks. Yes, that’s familiar; I’d just never seen a name given to it. If I have a few minutes at some point I think that I may be able to write down the functions $f_k$.

Comment: Thanks!! Looking forward to hearing from you again, and in the meanwhile, I will think about the Fibonacci approach :)

Comment: Hi @Brian M. Scott. Thank you very much for the added prove! It makes a lot of sense to me. Again, just to make sure, to get the GF for the general case, we simple take product of all $k$?

Comment: Sorry, not a product, its a sum

Comment: @CapitalSparrow: I’ve not checked to be sure that the calculations work out, but yes, that should work.

Comment: Thank you! Have a wonderful evening

Comment: @CapitalSparrow: You’re welcome!  You too.